# SELECT AS colName in inner join, colName doesn't exist (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I have a SELECT clause in a function in which I'm joining two tables in order to find restaurants that are within a certain distance of the user and currently open. For some reason, when I run this function I get the following
error:

```
ERROR: column "distance" does not exist
LINE 10:              distance < searchDist AND
                      ^
```

Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_nearby_open_restaurants (searchDist integer, myLat numeric, myLon numeric)
RETURNS json AS $$
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nearbyOpenRestaurants AS
    SELECT Restaurants.restaurantID, Restaurants.name, Restaurants.type, 
           Restaurants.address, Restaurants.deliveryDistance,
           (3959 * acos(cos(radians(myLat)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * 
            cos(radians(longitude) - radians(myLon)) + 
            sin(radians(myLat)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance,
           BusinessHours.hoursJSON
    FROM Restaurants, BusinessHours
    WHERE Restaurants.RestaurantID = BusinessHours.RestaurantID AND 
          distance < searchDist AND 
          distance < Restaurants.deliveryDistance
    /*Check if the restaurant is open here*/
    ;

RETURN to_json(nearbyOpenRestaurants);
DROP TABLE nearbyOpenRestaurants;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Just to clarify, the SELECT AS clause containing the distance calculation works just fine in its table, like so:

```
SELECT restaurantID, name, type, address, deliveryDistance,
    (3959 * acos(cos(radians(myLat)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * 
     cos(radians(longitude) - radians(myLon)) + 
     sin(radians(myLat)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance 
    FROM Restaurants
    HAVING distance < searchDist AND distance < deliveryDistance;
```

So the problem only exists when I'm joining two tables together. The HAVING clause doesn't seem to help in the joined SELECT either.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `distance` here is an alias in the `SELECT` that's not available yet in the `WHERE` clause. In a separate table it's just another column.

So, instead of `distance` in the `WHERE`, repeat the whole operation:

`sin(radians(myLat)) * sin(radians(latitude))))`

So your `WHERE` clause would become:

```
 WHERE Restaurants.RestaurantID = BusinessHours.RestaurantID AND 
          ( sin(radians(myLat)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) ) < searchDist AND 
         ( sin(radians(myLat)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) ) < Restaurants.deliveryDistance
```

I added enclosing parens to further delineate and add additional clarity.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

This repeating of calcuations is simply the way it needs to be done in *SQL* when you want to re-use a value from the `SELECT` in the `WHERE` of the same query. Generally, redoing a calculation isn't a big issue (I believe it has some caching in place to help with this), and I suspect that these calculations, which are straightforward math calculations, are no exception, so I would recommend going with this repeating method.

If you happened upon a case where something was truly an expensive query, and you found that the built-in caching did make repeating the expression to expensive, there are two options:

One is to use a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), which involves a `WITH` expression. This is good for independent queries, i.e. queries which do not depend on input from the query in which you'll be using it. This basically functions as a query-scoped temp table. However, in your case, your repeated expression is not constant -- it changes depending on the particular row from your `JOIN`ed tables -- and so a *CTE* would not work for you.

Another is to wrap your `SELECT` inside of another `SELECT`, moving the `WHERE` clause to the outer `SELECT` such that the `distance` column is available to you in the outer `SELECT`. However, with this approach, you would need to make sure your inner `SELECT` returned all the necessary columns that the outer `SELECT` needed in its `WHERE` clause, which would require adding columns in your case, and overall just seems more complicated of a query than it needs to be, although the complexity would probably be reduced a bit if the newer `JOIN` syntax was used where the criteria were moved outside of the `WHERE` and `JOIN ... ON` was used instead.

So, again, I would recommend repeating the expression. Only try to optimize further if absolutely necessary.

**Edit in repsonse to 2nd comment from OP:**

It shouldn't have anything to do with whether or not tables are joined -- referencing an aliased column from the `SELECT` won't work in a `HAVING` or `WHERE` clause in a singular table, either.

e.g.

```
mydb=# create table bar (id serial, val decimal);
CREATE TABLE
mydb=# insert into bar (val) values (1.2), (1.1), (3.2);
INSERT 0 3
mydb=# select * from bar;
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 | 1.2
  2 | 1.1
  3 | 3.2
(3 rows)

mydb=# select id, val, sin(val) from bar;
 id | val |         sin         
----+-----+---------------------
  1 | 1.2 |   0.932039085967226
  2 | 1.1 |   0.891207360061435
  3 | 3.2 | -0.0583741434275801
(3 rows)

mydb=# select id, val, sin(val) as narf from bar;
 id | val |        narf         
----+-----+---------------------
  1 | 1.2 |   0.932039085967226
  2 | 1.1 |   0.891207360061435
  3 | 3.2 | -0.0583741434275801
(3 rows)

mydb=# select id, val, sin(val) as narf from bar having narf > 0;
ERROR:  column "narf" does not exist
LINE 1: select id, val, sin(val) as narf from bar having narf > 0;
                                                         ^
mydb=# select id, val, sin(val) as narf from bar having sin(val) > 0;
ERROR:  column "bar.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select id, val, sin(val) as narf from bar having sin(val) > ...
               ^

mydb=# select id, val, sin(val) as narf from bar where narf > 0;
ERROR:  column "narf" does not exist
LINE 1: select id, val, sin(val) as narf from bar where narf > 0;
                                                        ^
mydb=# select id, val, sin(val) as narf from bar where sin(val) > 0;
 id | val |       narf        
----+-----+-------------------
  1 | 1.2 | 0.932039085967226
  2 | 1.1 | 0.891207360061435
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Hi, I've thought about doing this but it doesn't seem efficient to do the calculation twice. More importantly, I do need the distance column in the result table, which I'm returning as a json.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with aliasing it to `distance` in the `SELECT` -- you just can't use it in the `WHERE` -- but I wouldn't worry about performance with repeated calculations in general, especially for ones that are simpler in nature. More details in an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider your solutions. I'm just really confused why the `distance` alias is available to use in a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause in a `SELECT` statement in which I'm not joining tables. Could it be that a joined `SELECT` and an individual `SELECT` get executed in different orders? I edited my question to include code from an individual `SELECT` for clarification.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention my singular select worked in MariaDB, as I've recently switched from that to Postgres. So you're right that it won't work in Postgres, considering I haven't tried it. Anyway your selection wrapping method seems to be working for me, though I won't close this thread until I'm finished and completely sure. Thanks for the help! For other questions related to this code, do I need to open new question threads or may I ask them here?

Comment: Ah, MariaDB vs. Postgres would explain it. You're welcome re: the help. It sounds like you should accept my answer, since one of the options is one you've employed and resolved the issue. Re: additional questions, even related to this code, you should open new questions.